# Having an issue with a stored procedure SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure that i'm having some issues with.

I'm trying to lookup against my table `GOTWVotes` and if `VotedBy` hasn't voted before write the vote to the table(this is working) however if `VotedBy` has voted before not to write to the table and return `VoteCount` as 1.

Although it doesn't write to the table when `VotedBy` exists the value of `VoteCount`always appears to be 0

Any help would be appreciated

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Votes]
    @VotedMember BIGINT,
    @VotedBy BIGINT

    AS
    DECLARE @votecount INT

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION t_Transaction
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [GOTWVotes] WITH (TABLOCKX)

    SELECT @votecount = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[GOTWVotes] 
    WHERE [VotedBy] = @VotedBy
    IF @votecount = 0

    INSERT INTO 
        [dbo].[GOTWVotes] ([VotedMember],[VotedBy])
    VALUES
        (@VotedMember, @VotedBy)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION t_Transaction
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @votecount = -1
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t_Transaction
    END CATCH
        RETURN @votecount
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s - Done thanks

Comment: The intent of a stored procedure return code is to indicate success (zero) or warning/error (non-zero). Avoid using it to return data. Use an output parameter or result set instead.

Comment: Don't use `RETURN` use an `OUTPUT` parameter. Return is meant to return the success of an SP (0 for success anything else for failure), not data.

Comment: You beat me to it @DanGuzman ;)

Comment: You don't need to actually count votes to determine if matching rows exist - and sometimes this can be much less efficient. Just test for existence using "if exists (select * from dbo.GOTWVotes where VotedBy = @VotedBy)". In this case it is better to use not exists since you only want to insert a row when nothing exists. Don't over-complicate your code. And why do you need a exclusive table lock? And a single dml statement is atomic - a transaction here may be overkill.

Comment: And your code just ate the error - the caller of your procedure will have no idea that anything bad happened nor will you (or your code) be able to capture / diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i'm still very much new to this so trying to piece things together, not used `OUTPUT` before could you provide an example of how i could use this with my code. 

@SMor i want to lock the table while the table is being read to prevent someone from being able to vote again quickly and ending up with more than one vote, this seems to work but as mentioned i've just pieced things together from this fourm and google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Votes]
    @VotedMember BIGINT,
    @VotedBy BIGINT,
    @votecount INT OUTPUT

    AS

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION t_Transaction

    SET @votecount = 0
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[GOTWVotes] 
    WHERE [VotedBy] = @VotedBy)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
        [dbo].[GOTWVotes] ([VotedMember],[VotedBy])
    VALUES
        (@VotedMember, @VotedBy)        
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @votecount = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[GOTWVotes] 
    WHERE [VotedBy] = @VotedBy
    END


    COMMIT TRANSACTION t_Transaction
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @votecount = -1
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t_Transaction
    END CATCH
```

To Call above Stored procedure you need to write following code

```
DECLARE @votecount int
EXEC dbo.Votes @VotedMember = 0, -- bigint
    @VotedBy = 0, -- bigint
    @votecount = @votecount OUTPUT -- int

SELECT @votecount
```

Comment: i've tried the above and it works fine in SSMS thanks it the record doesn't exist it returns `0` and if the record does exists it return `1`, i'll now need to modify what i have in C# to read the `OUTPUT`

Comment: you need to add one more Parameter in c# as ParameterDirection.Output and you will get value in the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems so complicated.  I am thinking something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Votes] (
    @VotedMember BIGINT,
    @VotedBy BIGINT,
    @retval int output
) 
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO dbo.GOTWVotes (VotedMember, VotedBy)
    SELECT v.VotedMember, v.VotedBy
    FROM (VALUES (@VotedMember, @VotedBy)) v(VotedMember, VotedBy)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.GOTWVotes gwv
                      WHERE gwv.VotedBy = v.VotedBy
                     );
  SET @retval = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

I suspect that what you want to do could also be handled with constraints.